# How to get the value from a custom attribute of a button in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

say for instance I have the following button in a form in asp.net mvc 3 app:

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="Click me" data-custom="D" />
```

I know how to get the value from the button.. however do I get the data-custom attr value in an action method? Thank you very much!!

Edit:

I should note that I'm not allowed to use javascript at all since this is a mobile version of the site for devices that do not support javascript..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however do I get the data-custom attr value in an action method?

No you don't. There is nothing in the HTML specification that indicates that data-* attributes should be sent to the server when submitting a form. So if you want to get that value you will need to use javascript. One technique consists in subscribing to the submit event of the form and then automatically injecting a hidden field into that form which will be populated from the data-* attribute of the submit button. This way the value will be sent to the server.

But since I suspect that what you are trying to achieve here is that you have multiple submit buttons and you want to know which button was clicked in your controller action. In this case you could use the following:

```
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="S">Save</button>
<button type="submit" name="btn" value="D">Delete</button>
...
```

and then have your controller action take an argument called `btn`.

But personally I prefer to use separate actions otherwise it makes the controller action very ugly since it will contain lots of if statements. Here's a [nice blog post](http://blog.ashmind.com/2010/03/15/multiple-submit-buttons-with-asp-net-mvc-final-solution/) I would invite you to checkout.

Comment: BINGO!! I did not know you could set the text of the button this way!! Thank you very much Darin. Pozdrav od Makedonija :) - I'll mark your answer as correct in 4 minutes. So zdravje

Answer (score 0):

A custom attribute is not passed through get or post; only values do.

You can grab the custom attribute value from client side (for example using jQuery .attr() function) and add it to your form data before submitting it.

Comment: I'm building a mobile app which should support javascript enabled devices as well as old devices which do not support javascript. I've developed the javascript version using jquery mobile. However I'm not allowed to use jquery in this project at all. I know how to get that value via javascript.. Any idea?

Comment: Why not an hidden input?
<input type="hidden" name="data-custom" value="D" />

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know you can't get data directly from data-... . you can write javascript to get this value.

Answer (score 0):

Only the value and the name of the form element are posted within a `form` and any `data-*` cannot be passed.

You can consider a workaround using `JavaScript`. The idea is to so somehow merge the `data-custom` value to your `value` attribute.

```
$("input[type=textbox][data-custom]").each(function(index, value) {
   $(value).attr("value", $(value).attr("value") + "$$$" + $(value).attr("data-custom"));
});
```

And from your action method, use `data.split("$$$")[1]` to get `data-custom`.

Hope this helps